# UICollectionView in UITableView - I want to show data in CollectionVewCell

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to show data in `UICollectionView`. Which is coming from `UITableView` cell. My main concern is this. I am passing a key `catgID` from `cellForRowAt` in another API and getting data from it. But data is not coming proper way.

I am passing `catgID` from `cellForRowAt` and getting in another API which will show the list of data for `UICollectionViewCells`. Now data is coming but not in proper way.

1. This is my `UITableView` class for `tableview` index.

```
import UIKit
import Reachability
import Alamofire


var arrayMenuProducts = [structMenuProducts]()
struct structMenuProducts {
    var id:Int
    var product_name:String
    var category:String
    var product_image:String
    var price:String
    var unit_price:Double
    var addons:NSArray
}


class MenuVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var reachability = Reachability()!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!


    var arrayMenuCat = [structMenuCat]()
    struct structMenuCat{
        var id:Int
        var category_name:String
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        menuVegAPI()
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayMenuCat.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        catgID = arrayMenuCat[indexPath.row].id

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1") as! MenuTableCell
        cell.lblCategoryTitle.text = arrayMenuCat[indexPath.row].category_name
        cell.collectionviewOne.reloadData()
//        let catid = arrayMenuCat[indexPath.row].id
//        print(catid)


        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 216
    }




    func menuVegAPI()
    {
        if (reachability.connection == .wifi) || (reachability.connection == .cellular)
        {
            arrayMenuCat.removeAll()
            SwiftLoader.show(animated: true)
            let url = BaseUrl + ViewController.sharedInstance.menuCategory
            print(url)

            Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
                SwiftLoader.hide()
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    let json = response.result.value
                        print(json)

                    let code = (json as AnyObject).object(forKey: "code") as! Int
                    print(code)

                    if code == 200
                    {
                        let data = (json as AnyObject).object(forKey: "data") as? NSArray

                        for alldata in data!
                        {
                            let id = (alldata as AnyObject).object(forKey: "id") as! Int
                            let category_name = (alldata as AnyObject).object(forKey: "category_name") as! String
                            let arr = structMenuCat(id: id, category_name: category_name)
                            self.arrayMenuCat.append(arr)
//                            self.menuProductsAPI(categoryid: id)

                        }
                        self.tableview.reloadData()

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                case .failure:
                    print("error")
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert(title: "", message: "Please Check Your Internet Connection")
        }

    }
}
```

2. This is my `TableViewCell` type class. In this class I am show data on `CollectionView`. Its code is here

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import Reachability

var catgID : Int!
var collectionreload : UICollectionView?

class MenuTableCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


    var reachability = Reachability()!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblCategoryTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionviewOne: UICollectionView!


    var arrayMenuProducts = [structMenuProducts]()
    struct structMenuProducts {
        var id:Int
        var product_name:String
        var category:String
        var product_image:String
        var price:String
        var unit_price:Double
        var addons:NSArray
    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        collectionreload = self.collectionviewOne
        print(arrayMenuProducts)
        print(catgID ?? 0)

        menuProductsAPI(categoryid: catgID!)
    }




    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }




    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return arrayMenuProducts.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellRID", for: indexPath) as! MenuCollectionViewCell

        let abc = arrayMenuProducts[indexPath.row].product_name
            print(abc)

            //        if catgID == Int(arrayMenuProducts[indexPath.row].category)
            //        {
            cell.lblTitleForVeg.text = arrayMenuProducts[indexPath.row].product_name
            cell.lblForPriceVeg.text = "$\(arrayMenuProducts[indexPath.row].unit_price)"

    }


    func menuProductsAPI(categoryid:Int)
    {
        if (reachability.connection == .wifi) || (reachability.connection == .cellular)
        {
            SwiftLoader.show(animated: true)
            arrayMenuProducts.removeAll()
            let url = BaseUrl + ViewController.sharedInstance.menuProducts + "categoryid=\(categoryid)"
            print(url)

            Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    let json = response.result.value
                    print(json)
                    //                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                    let code = (json as AnyObject).object(forKey: "code") as! Int
                    print(code)

                    if code == 200
                    {
                        let data = (json as AnyObject).object(forKey: "data") as? NSArray

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            for alldata in data!
                            {
                                let id = (alldata as AnyObject).object(forKey: "id") as! Int
                                let product_name = (alldata as AnyObject).object(forKey: "product_name") as! String
                                let category = (alldata as AnyObject).object(forKey: "category") as! String
                                let product_image = (alldata as AnyObject).object(forKey: "product_image") as! String
                                let price = (alldata as AnyObject).object(forKey: "price") as! String
                                let unit_price = (alldata as AnyObject).object(forKey: "unit_price") as! Double
                                let addons = (alldata as AnyObject).object(forKey: "addons") as? NSArray


                                let arr = structMenuProducts(id: id, product_name: product_name, category: category, product_image: product_image, price: price, unit_price: unit_price, addons: addons!)
                                self.arrayMenuProducts.append(arr)
                            }
                            self.collectionviewOne.reloadData()
                            SwiftLoader.hide()
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                case .failure:
                    print("error")
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //            alert(title: "", message: "Please Check Your Internet Connection")
        }

    }

}
```

I want to show data coming in `CollectionView` in a proper formate. If `Tableview index == 0` and Category id is coming 10 then. Category id 10 will first then one by one in a sequence I want to pass category id. In my case Category id is not coming in a queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the tableview datasource method as

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1") as! MenuTableCell
        cell.lblCategoryTitle.text = arrayMenuCat[indexPath.row].category_name    
        cell.menuProductsAPI(categoryid: arrayMenuCat[indexPath.row].id)
        return cell
    }
```

And remove `menuProductsAPI(categoryid: catgID!)` from `awakeFromNib` method

Comment: Hi, I had already tried this but with this way. When I am scrolling tableview then the then the Id is going in another index like : (if index 0  Category id is 1) after scroll (index 0 then Category id will be change like 2,3,4 another categories assigned to index 0)

Comment: @Coding It won't change like this. Try print(indexPath.row,arrayMenuCat[indexPath.row].id) in cellforrow

Comment: Printing properly but data is showing on screen same

Comment: @Coding Don't create any variable outside the viewcontroller class. Your code is confusing

Comment: please share your WhatsApp number then I will share my project on google drive.

Comment: @Coding Paste the drive link here

Comment: have you check it.

Comment: this is my number eight eight eight two two nine two two one nine

Comment: tell me if you download complete then I will delete it.

Comment: @Coding I didn't get the link. post now

Comment: I have done it. But I have a issue in it. if I am scrolling fast then all data is showing in disorder way . If I am scrolling very slow then it's working fine.

Comment: I am doing in MenuVC Class and its Tableviewcell type class name is MenuTableCell

Comment: any solution in it.

Comment: @Coding Replace these 2 files https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-XjNW2c21XlO7jDIxJ_FvftgcMs0h-eq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Coding Use https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher to store images in cache